# How to create local repository for Ubuntu Snappy

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-core

How to create local repository for Ubuntu Snappy?
For example I use reprepro to create Ubuntu repository for deb packages.

Comment: What do you mean by how? If you know how to use reprepro to create a repository, then what's the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can "snappy install" a snap directly on a machine, but there isn't an equivalent to the idea of a local repository. In future, it will be possible to control snaps by policy across an organisation, but for now you'll need to use SSH to do that.